# How to break inside an haml loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, haml, break

It could be a stupid question, but that is why I prefer to ask here.

I have this code below in HAML:

```
- @calendar[:array_number_day].each.with_index do |num_d, index|
  %tr
  - (0..6).each do |i|
    - if (@calendar[:array_name_day][index] == i)
      %td
        %span #{num_d} 
    - else
      %td
```

How can I break the each loop in this case ? I tried `#{break}` and `break` after `%span #{num_d}` but without success.

Thank's in advance for the help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- break` should work:

```
- @calendar[:array_number_day].each.with_index do |num_d, index|
  %tr
  - (0..6).each do |i|
    - if (@calendar[:array_name_day][index] == i)
      %td
        %span #{num_d}
      - break
    - else
      %td
```

Make sure you have `-` and use the proper indentation (it should be one indentation level deeper than the `if` statement.